Search in files and folders on Powershell
I've been racking my brain for several days now and I can't get the script to work properly.
my basic knowledge of powershell does not allow me to finish this work. Please help me or direct me where I can see it.
I have a code on powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width = 1000
$form.Height = 800
$form.Text = "search"
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


$filePathTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$filePathTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$filePathTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 25)
$form.Controls.Add($filePathTextBox)

$searchTextTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$searchTextTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 40)
$searchTextTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 25)
$form.Controls.Add($searchTextTextBox)


$openFileButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$openFileButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 70)
$openFileButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 25)
$openFileButton.Text = "Open file"
$openFileButton.Add_Click({
  
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.Filter = "Все файлы (*.*)|*.*"
    $openFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $filePathTextBox.Text = $openFileDialog.FileName
})
$form.Controls.Add($openFileButton)

$openFolderButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$openFolderButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120, 70)
$openFolderButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 25)
$openFolderButton.Text = "Open folder"
$openFolderButton.Add_Click({
    
    $openFolderDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $folderPath = $openFolderDialog.SelectedPath 
    $filePathTextBox.Text = $folderPath
})
$form.Controls.Add($openFolderButton)



$findButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$findButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210, 105)
$findButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 25)
$findButton.Text = "search"
$findButton.Add_Click({
    
    $filePath = $filePathTextBox.Text
    $searchText = $searchTextTextBox.Text
    
    if (-not [System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath)) {
        $resultLabel.Text = "File not found" } else {
 $results = Get-Content $filePath | Where-Object { $_ -match $searchText }
        $resultLabel.Text = $results -join [Environment]::NewLine
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($findButton)



$findButtonfolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$findButtonfolder.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310, 105)
$findButtonfolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 25)
$findButtonfolder.Text = "Search in folder"
$findButtonfolder.Add_Click({
    
    $filePath = $filePathTextBox.Text
    $searchText = $searchTextTextBox.Text

    $results = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.FullName -like "*$searchText*" }

    $resultLabel.Text = ($results | ForEach-Object { $_.Path }) -join [Environment]::NewLine
})
$form.Controls.Add($findButtonfolder)

$resultLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$resultLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 105)
$resultLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 100)
$form.Controls.Add($resultLabel)



$saveAndSelectPathButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$saveAndSelectPathButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(500, 170)
$saveAndSelectPathButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 25)
$saveAndSelectPathButton.Text = "Save to file"
$saveAndSelectPathButton.Add_Click({
    
    $saveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $savePathTextBox.Text = $saveFileDialog.FileName
    
        $filePath = $filePathTextBox.Text
    $searchText = $searchTextTextBox.Text
    
    if (-not [System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath)) {
        $resultLabel.Text = "File not found"
    } else {
        $results = Get-Content $filePath | Where-Object { $_ -match $searchText }
        $results | Out-File -FilePath $savePathTextBox.Text -Encoding utf8
        $resultLabel.Text = "Save results in file $($savePathTextBox.Text)"
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($saveAndSelectPathButton)

$savePathTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$savePathTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(600, 105)
$savePathTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 25)
$form.Controls.Add($savePathTextBox)



$closeButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$closeButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 210)
$closeButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 25)
$closeButton.Text = "Close"
$closeButton.Add_Click({
    $form.Close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($closeButton)




$form.ShowDialog()

The file search is working fine, but the folder search is not working.
I need to add the ability to search by a specific mask and implement a search for a variety of files in a folder with the hostname of the device.
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport voice vlan 92
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport voice vlan 92
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
!

the input will contain information about the cisco configuration file and I need to find the necessary blocks in the configuration with information output in the form of :
Hostname:
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport voice vlan 92
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast edge
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
!


Most likely the issue is in the line:
$resultLabel.Text = ($results | ForEach-Object { $_.Path }) -join [Environment]::NewLine

FileInfo instances don't have a .Path property. What you wanted most likely was:
$resultLabel.Text = $results.FullName -join [Environment]::NewLine

In the previous line you could also leverage the -Filter assuming you want to match file's .Name instead of .FullName, so:
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -File -Filter "*$searchText*"

Instead of:
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.FullName -like "*$searchText*" }

